# how to avoid calling callback function in children list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML parent-list named "sub-menu" and inside it there is a child list "sub-menu-real".

```
<li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">HIDE<span class="sub-arrows"></span></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu-real">
      <li class="sub-menu-l1"><a href="#">Hide Level 1</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu-l2"><a href="#">Hide Level 2</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu-l3"><a href="#">Hide Level 3</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu-l4"><a href="#">Hide Level 4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The problem is that when I use JQuery to define a callback function when the "sub-menu" is clicked, the callback function is called also when I click the children.

Here is the Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".sub-menu").click(function(){
    callbackFunction();
}); 


$(".sub-menu-l1").click(function(){});

$(".sub-menu-l2").click(function(){});

$(".sub-menu-l3").click(function(){});

$(".sub-menu-l4").click(function(){});
```

Here I just call the callBackFunction inside the `.sub-menu` class but it is called when I click sub-menu children.

How can I avoid this problem ?

Comment: You could do `$(".sub-menu > a")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to stop [event bubbling](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) when triggering a `click` event on the children.

Something like this:

```
$(".sub-menu").click(function() {
   callbackFunction();
});

$('.sub-menu-l1,.sub-menu-l2,.sub-menu-l3,.sub-menu-l4').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added an `EventListener` to the wrapping `<li>` element with the class of `sub-menu`. As long as your children are wrapped into that element, the click handler will be called by clicking on the element (and those children are part of that element).

So if you want to get rid of this behaviour you need to remove that listener:

```
$(".sub-menu").click(function(){
  callbackFunction();
});
```

Otherwise every click on an element inside of `.sub-menu` will call that click handler.

Comment: I can't remove the children listner because I use it to define other callback functions when I click in children (other functions different from those of a parent )

Comment: you dont need to remove the children listeners but the one on the parent element

Answer (score 0):

`e.stopPropagation()` can be used on child elements . Hope this helps

```js
$(".sub-menu").click(function(e){
 
    callbackFunction();
}); 
$(".sub-menu-real li").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
});

function callbackFunction()
{
   alert(1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">HIDE<span class="sub-arrows"></span></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu-real">
      <li class="sub-menu-l1"><a href="#">Hide Level 1</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu-l2"><a href="#">Hide Level 2</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu-l3"><a href="#">Hide Level 3</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu-l4"><a href="#">Hide Level 4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `a` element as trigger for the `click` event:

```
$(".sub-menu-click > a").click(function(e){
  callbackFunction();
});
```